# Cloudformation sub function for cloudwatch dashboard body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sam, aws-cloud9

I'm running into issues using the !Sub intrinsic cloudformation function with AWS::Region pseudoparameter within the body of my cloudwatch dashboard (to ensure my stack is region agnostic).  The cloudformation I am using is given below

```
  OrderDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardBody:  !Sub  '{  "widgets": [    {      "type": "metric",      "x": 6,      "y": 0,      "width": 6,      "height": 6,      "properties": {        "metrics": [          [ "address", "validateAddressApiLatency" ]        ],        "view": "timeSeries",        "stacked": false,        "region": "${AWS::Region}",        "title": "ValidateAddressApiSuccessLatencyP99",        "period": 300,        "stat": "p99"      }    },    {      "type": "metric",      "x": 12,      "y": 0,      "width": 8,      "height": 6,      "properties": {        "metrics": [          [ "address", "validateAddressApiErrorLatency" ]        ],        "view": "timeSeries",        "stacked": false,        "region": "${AWS::Region}",        "title": "ValidateAddressApiErrorLatencyP99",        "period": 300,        "stat": "p99"      }    },    {      "type": "text",      "x": 0,      "y": 0,      "width": 6,      "height": 6,      "properties": {        "markdown": "# Heading \nThis dashboard exists to show that our success latency metric and error latency metric are published successfully using a single annotation and aspectj.\n\nThe first row shows the 99th percentile latencies, and the bottom column shows the count of the number of calls"      }    },    {      "type": "metric",      "x": 6,      "y": 6,      "width": 6,      "height": 6,      "properties": {        "metrics": [          [ { "expression": "SELECT COUNT(validateAddressApiLatency) FROM SCHEMA(address)", "label": "NumberOfSuccessfulCalls", "id": "q1", "region": "${AWS::Region}" } ]        ],        "view": "timeSeries",        "stacked": false,        "region": "${AWS::Region}",        "stat": "Average",        "period": 300,        "title": "NumberOfSuccessfulValidateCalls"      }    },    {      "type": "metric",      "x": 12,      "y": 6,      "width": 6,      "height": 6,      "properties": {        "metrics": [          [ { "expression": "SELECT COUNT(validateAddressApiErrorLatency) FROM SCHEMA(address)", "label": "NumberOfErroredCalls", "id": "q1", "region": "${AWS::Region}" } ]        ],        "view": "timeSeries",        "stacked": false,        "region": "${AWS::Region}",        "stat": "Average",        "period": 300,        "title": "NumberOfErrorValidateCalls"     }    }  ]}'
      DashboardName: order-dashboard
```

When I deploy the dashboard, the region is not substituted
[image]

The interesting thing is I use sub with the region parameter other places in the template, it works.

```
Outputs:
  OrderApiUrl:
    Description: "The endpoint you can use to place orders.  Make sure to append the order id to the end"
    Value: !Sub "https://${OrderApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/v1/orders/"
```

Any idea on what I can do to get the value substituted?  Thanks

Comment: I would multiline the DashboardBody so it is easier to read and maybe easier to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ErikAsplund, something like:

```
  OrderDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: order-dashboard
      DashboardBody: !Sub |
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
              "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                  "AWS/Lambda",
                  "Duration",
                  "FunctionName",
                  "${MyReference}"
                ]
              }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The code that you provided **works perfectly fine**. Thus the issue that you have must be related to other factors than your CloudFormation code in the question.

Maybe you are using some other code, not the one in the question.

Comment: I’ve deleted and redeployed my stack, as well as recloning the entire repo. I’ve deleted the resource by commenting it out, then creating it again. I’ve made slight changes to force an update; however the issue still persists. Given that it doesn’t work for me, do you have any more advice marcin? Thank you

Comment: @ConnorButch The evidence is I deployed your code and it worked as expected.